# Upgrading to spring boot 2.1.3 to 2.1.4 giving tomcat exception while starting

Tags: spring-boot

I have updated my spring parent from 2.1.3 to 2.1.4 Release, so after I am getting some exceptions while starting the applications. is there any version problem?

command used for run : mvn spring-boot:run

java version :11

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample.business</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-order-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>sample-order-service</name>
    <description>sample Order Service</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent> 

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <jaxb-runtime.version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</jaxb-runtime.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.M1</spring-cloud.version>
        <sample.version>1.0</sample.version>
        <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
        <json.version>20180813</json.version>
        <mysql.version>8.0.11</mysql.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.6</commons-io.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <commons-pool2.version>2.5.0</commons-pool2.version>
        <redis.version>2.9.1</redis.version>
        <velocity.version>1.7</velocity.version>
        <velocity-tools.version>2.0</velocity-tools.version>
        <logstash-logback-encoder.version>5.3</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.6</httpclient.version>
        <env>dev</env>
    </properties>   

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Start: Spring Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: Spring Libraries -->

        <!-- Adding JAXB Runtime since it is not shipped with JDK 9+ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-runtime.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Start: Swagger Libraries -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: Swagger Libraries -->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Json Web Token Binary -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logstash Log Encoder -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId> 
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId> 
            <version>${logstash-logback-encoder.version}</version> 
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-pool2.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>${redis.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>       

        <!-- velocity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>${velocity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${velocity-tools.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Start: Spring Boot and Security Test Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: Spring Boot and Security Test Libraries -->

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>sample-order-service</finalName>
        <filters>
            <filter>${env}-build.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Automatic-Module-Name>com.sample.business.order</Automatic-Module-Name>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories> 
</project>
```

logs:

```
2019-05-14 18:40:30.277  INFO [sample-order-service,,,] 10916 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8083 (http)
2019-05-14 18:40:30.494 ERROR [sample-order-service,,,] 10916 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:427)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:180)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
        at com.sample.business.order.OrderServiceApplication.main(OrderServiceApplication.java:30)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:181)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5060)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1178)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 45 common frames omitted

2019-05-14 18:40:30.579 ERROR [sample-order-service,,,] 10916 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:427)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:180)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
        at com.sample.business.order.OrderServiceApplication.main(OrderServiceApplication.java:30)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 35 common frames omitted
```

I tried with clean build and maven repos still no luck. is ther any version problem ?

Comment: There is a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`. Check your dependencies, there is a missing or wrong versioned dependency.

Comment: It seems your classpath contains a version of servlet-api that is too old. Execute `mvn dependency:tree` to see what dependencies are pulled in, see if any of them relies on an old servlet API version.

Comment: Thanks @Gimby for the help. there was a conflict between java servlet. so I excluded the java-servlet from velocity-tools, then its worked for me

Comment: You probably have a very old version of velocity tools, the 2.0 version declares the servlet-api as provided which means it should not be automatically dumped on your application's classpath.  Maybe upgrading the dependency works just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem like this generally means that you have a dependency on your classpath which is too old. This can happen when using a tool like Maven because it has the concept of **transitive dependencies**, which means dependencies that are pulled in because another dependency dictates that you need them. It is convenient... and prone to errors.

From the exception stacktrace it is quite clear that it is to do with a servlet class, which implies that it is the servlet-api.jar (googling for a classname is generally an easy way to figure out what jar a class is part of if you don't happen to know it by experience).

Knowing which jar it likely is, you can execute the maven command

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to make Maven generate a listing of all the dependencies, their versions and their scopes. Searching through this you can find where that jar is pulled in.

So in this case as mentioned in the comments, a dependency velocity-tools was pulling in the servlet-api and it was an older version (version 2.3 I am going to guess by looking at the [pom of that dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity-tools/1.3)). Knowing this there are a few basic steps you can take to remedy the situation. Here are three I commonly apply and one that is a bad idea.

**1. Remove the offending dependency (velocity-tools in this case)**

This is only relevant if you don't actually need that dependency of course. This is actually true more often than it should be when it comes to Maven poms, we all like to copy/paste just a little too carelessly.

**2. Upgrade the dependency**

Maybe the root dependency is needed, but a very old version is still being used. Dependency problems can be resolved in newer updates (which also seems to be the case for velocity-tools). Historically, dependencies in maven central did not exactly pay too much attention to declaring the right scopes for their transitive dependencies and could put far more dependencies on compile scope than was actually necessary. This has improved a lot in recent years, but you can still run into problems when including very old dependency versions.

**3. Declare the right version and scope of the transitive dependency yourself**

Say servlet-api is being pulled in on compile scope - that is **wrong**. Servlet-api must never be deployed with your application, the server (Tomcat) **provides** it. It is a dependency who's purpose is literally only so you can compile code that uses the servlet API.

So if you do find yourself in the situation where a dependency must be included for compilation but excluded from deployment, you can manage it yourself in the pom (or in your parent pom) which will take precedence.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**4. Add an exclusion (not recommended)**

If you actually do need the root dependency it may still be that the transitive dependency being pulled in, servlet-api in this case, is not relevant to your code at all. In that case you can add an exclusion.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Exclusions should be a last resort as they are hard to maintain; they are essentially a hack. Adding an exclusion to one dependency does not guarantee that the dependency disappears because it may be pulled in somewhere else too. Whenever possible manage the dependency through one of the other three options, try to avoid working with exclusions.